# PyInstaller error: loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to generate exe file of my Python project (with Dash).

I've got the errors after execution:

c:\Projects\bin\Test>test_server.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src\server.py", line 22, in 
File "c:\projects...\bin\build_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "src\uss_gui\app.py", line 10, in 
File "c:\projects...bin\build_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "src\uss_gui\DashAppWrapper.py", line 9, in 
File "c:\projects...\bin\build_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "lib\site-packages\dash_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
File "c:\projects...\bin\build_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 19, in 
File "c:\projects...\bin\build_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "lib\site-packages\flask_*init*_.py", line 19, in 
File "c:\projects...\bin\build_env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "lib\site-packages\flask\json_*init*_.py", line 15, in 
ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous'
[22768] Failed to execute script server

Could someone please  to help me with this issue?

Anton

Comment: the error is at the end: ` ImportError: cannot import name 'json'`.  please supply minimal code to reproduce the error.

Comment: thank you for your respond. I guess the problem is in importlib_metadata-4.11.3-py3.7.egg-info, I see it in bin\test_server\.... Before I had importlib_metadata-4.10.1-py3.7.egg-info. How can I downgrade it? I used pip install importlib_metadata == 4.10.1, but it does not help

Comment: this would be helpful to answer further:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example